# Inspiron 5520 (originally ubuntu). Seller had changed to Win7. I want to go UBUNTU. Pls Help

Tags: wireless, drivers, dell

I bought an inspiron 5520 here in Thailand and the seller had installed windows. I only use my laptop for education so I have decided to go with Ubuntu. i noticed that the internal wifi card is not working. How can I fix the laptop and get the Wi-Fi working? Thanks. I am a newbee. ;)

```
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

Comment: As  I understood, you have installed Ubuntu already, but you have problems with some hardware. Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command. This will help to fix the internal wireless adapter. Regarding other problems please ask separate questions.

Comment: Edited. How should I do that? I am not familiar with the language and terms in the answer. I appreciate your help and pls excuse my ignorance. Thanks.

Comment: Are your problems in windows or problems because of which the seller changed from ubuntu to windows? I have always used the Ubuntu on usb from which I would first check the hardware is running and then install. http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Comment: Open terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T, enter there the command and post output to your question. After that I will help to install drivers.

Comment: I am using ubuntu now. It's my first day running solely Ubuntu on my laptop from the HD. I tested the OS by booting from USB. Liked what I saw, actually reminds me of Amiga, and I am now hopefully going to become an ubuntu user.

Comment: Are you connected to internet via external adapter or a wire?

Comment: External adaptor. It's running at about 10% of its speed before switching from windows to Ubuntu. It's an Asus N14. The main reason I asked the question was bc I dont understand the drivers situation on ubuntu. I cant utilize the install DVD for the adaptor either because I dont know how to deal with the files in the folder for Linux install. I wont be using the internal adaptor very often but I would like to get it functionable again. I will hopefully keep it switched off when I am using the external.

Comment: You can ask a separate question regarding the external adapter. It probably needs a driver too. But why you need an external adapter, if you have an internal one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: I am sensitive to the wifi. I can also dowse for water. Supposedly many others who can dowse also have the same preferences or sensitivities. your answer fixed everything and it was basically automatic. I have been told that Ubuntu might be difficult, but that was astoundingly trouble-free. All I can say is "wow" and thanks.

Comment: Okay but I cant switch the internal one off now without switching both off. that would be a worrisome situation I had just gotten into for me. How can I switch the internal one off? Am I missing an option? I tried  settings>>command also but when I switch either one off, they both switch. If this cant be done, I am looking at a reinstall

Comment: (or I will just need to uninstall the drivers) otherwise, I will get ill

Comment: No, you do not have to uninstall drivers.

Comment: I can't figure it out. I can only switch both off or both on. How exactly can I switch solely the internal one off while keeping the external?

Comment: OK. Ask a separate question. I will ask for some output and give you the command. But first try `sudo modprobe -r wl` to turn off and `sudo modprobe wl` to turn on.

Comment: That worked instantly. I think people these days have not given command solutions the chance they deserve. instead of a menu which changes with multiple paths to multiple specific interfaces with more or less priveleges relatively, Command often does the job, performing multiple tasks, as fast as possible, and with less possibilities for user error. All the best. Thanks again...... I tried upvoting your answer but it wont show till I do a bit more to prove I am not a robot to this site:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are connected to internet via some other adapter wired or wireless, run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

and the internal adapter should work.

Or go to System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers

and install the driver.

Both methods do the same thing.

Comment: Will I be able to use that command to switch it off and on

Comment: You do not need commands to switch wireless. Just click network indicator in the top bar and you can do it there. This command installs a driver.

Comment: I can only switch both adapters on or off together in the controls at the top, I cant switch only the internal one off. Could I switch the internal one off via command?

Comment: Yes, you can. But isn't it easier to use hardware buttons like Fn+F2 or some else Fx button with a wireless sign?